# How do I make an event Listener (onclick) for a single Table Cell

Tags: javascript, html

My question is: How can I make a table cell, for example, change text on click?
I tried this:

```js
function randomFunction() {
  document.getElementById("randomId").innerText = "random text"
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="randomId" onclick="randomFunction()">random text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it does the `onclick` attribute for the entire row.

Is it possible to trigger the function only when I click on the cell ?

Comment: There's only one cell in the row, how can you tell the difference? And you're changing the text to the same text it already had.

Comment: Your code should do what you want already. Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: what "does the onclick attribute for the entire row." are you referring to?

Comment: sorry, bad example. But I solved it with Maik Lowrey's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it possible. you have pass the context to the function. I put more cells in your table.

```js
function randomFunction(e){
  e.innerText = "HuhU"
    // document.getElementById("randomId").innerText = "random text!"
}
```

```css
td {
  background: green;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="randomId" onclick="randomFunction(this)">random text</td>
        <td id="randomId" onclick="randomFunction(this)">random text</td>
        <td id="randomId" onclick="randomFunction(this)">random text</td>      
    </tr>
</table>
```